# dbms_parallel_execute.task_status gives invalid status 4

Tags: plsql

For what reason dbms_parallel_execute.task_status returns 4. Below is my issue.
This job was ruining multiple times without records to process. and finally it started going out of the loop at point it calls dbms_parallel_execute.resume_task(l_task)
I have the values that has for L_try and L_status during the run-time 
Have used dbms_parallel_execute.create_chunks_by_rowid
L_status = 4 and L_try = 0 and it goes out of the loop at below bold point..
Please help .. What need to be done to get the process running smooth again

```
       L_try := 0;
        L_status := DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.TASK_STATUS(l_task);
        dbms_output.put_line(L_status);

        WHILE(l_try < 2 and L_status != DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.FINISHED) 
        LOOP  

          dbms_output.put_line(L_try);
          L_try := l_try + 1;

          **DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.RESUME_TASK(l_task);**
          L_status := DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.TASK_STATUS(l_task);

        END LOOP;
```

Comment: How do you perform chunking ? Can you show ?

Answer (score 1):

Status 4 stands for NO_CHUNKS:

```
  NO_CHUNKS             CONSTANT NUMBER := 4;
```

So most probably you just don't generate any chunks for processing. There is no data to be processed.

You should avoid running task (`DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.RUN_TASK`) if there's nothing to do.

Comment: So do we have to handle that in the above code. As it unexpectedly exists for  program at the point of  **DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.RESUME_TASK(l_task);**

Comment: You should avoid running task (`DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.RUN_TASK`) if there's nothing to do.

Comment: Thank you  Maxim. I will put a condition not to execute the parallel processing, if there are no records to process.